# Error on Xcode Thread 1 SIGBART - Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I am making a program to determine whether a number is prime or not. I had a working code on myPlayground , and when i implemented it into Xcode i got this error.

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{ 'Thread 1 SIGBART'

This error has happened before, even when i seem to write the code correctly. Please check for any error in my code and give me some solutions. This is only the first part which determines if the number is prime to test whether it would work or not, the other part of the code will be implemented when the problem is resolved.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController { 
        @IBOutlet weak var enteredNumber: UITextField!

        @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

        @IBAction func CheckIfPrime(sender: AnyObject) { 

        var n = enteredNumber.text.toInt()!

        while n != 2 && n % 2 != 0 { 

            for var i = 2; i <= n; i + 1 { 

                if n % i != 0 { 
                    var v = resultLabel.text
                    v = "Is Prime"
                } 

            } 

        } 

    } 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    } 

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { 
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    } 


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIGBART errors occur when your code references an object that is inexistent. Go to you IB storyboard(where your labels, buttons, and text fields are) and click on any item that is linked to your view controller. For each one, click on the right most item of the inspector(the arrow within the circle) If you see more than one connection, that is why the error happens. Delete any connections that you think should not be there. (Or, just to be safe, delete all connections and manually reconnect everything by right clicking the UI element and drag to the IBOutlet/Action name)

Comment: it worked , i was referencing an outlet and action , to an IB ACTION so all i had to do was delete the referenced outlet and only keep the action thank you